# Loading OS image from floppy disk without INT 13 of BIOS Service

Tags: operating-system, linux-device-driver, bootloader, disk, bios

How can I load OS image from floppy disk to memory without BIOS Service while booting my PC?

The only way I’ve used is calling int13h in real mode .

I got to know that I need to handle with ‘Disk controller’ . 
Do I need to write kinda ‘Device driver’ in [BIT 16] real mode and is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you have to do direct I/O with certain I/O ports (if we speak of x86 platform) and basically reimplement the floppy driver in your code which BIOS **needs somehow to run anyway**.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know ! Do you know more details about it?

Comment: You can take SeaBIOS source code. You it’s open source project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 0andriy has commented, you will have to communicate with the floppy controller directly, bypassing the BIOS.  (Which BTW, why do you want to do such a thing?  The BIOS was made specifically so you don't have to do this.  Is it solely because you want to, maybe to learn how to program the FDC? I'm okay with that.)

The FDC (Floppy Disk Controller) is of the ISA (Industry Standard Architecture) era, back when I/O ports were hard coded to specific addresses.  The FDC came in many variants, but most followed a standard rule.  The original 756 was a common FDC, with later (still really old to today's standards) controllers following the 82077AA variant.

These controllers had twelve (12) registers using eight (8) I/O Byte addresses, Base + 00h to Base + 07h.  (Please note that a single I/O address can be two registers if one is a read and one is a write.)  You read and write to these registers to instruct the FDC to do things, such as start the motor for drive 1.  (For fun: Did you know that the FDC was originally capable of handling four drives?)

This isn't to difficult to do, but now you have to have some way for the ISA bus to communicate with the FDC and the main memory.  In comes the DMA (Direct Memory Access).  Now you have to also program the DMA to make the transfers.

Here is the catch.  If you don't have all of the FDC and DMA code within the first 512 bytes of the floppy, the 512 bytes the BIOS loaded for you already, there is no way to load the remaining sectors.  For example, you can't have your DMA code in the second sector of your boot code expecting to call it, since you have to use that DMA to load that sector in the first place.  All FDC and DMA code, at least a minimum read service, *must* be in the first sector of the disk.  This is quite difficult to do, reliably.

I am not saying it is impossible to do, I am just saying it is improbable.  For one thing, if you can do it (reliably) in 512 bytes, I would like to see it.  It might be a fun experiment.  Anyway, do a search for FDC, DMA, etc., things I wrote of here.  There are many examples on the web.  If you wish to read a book about it, I [wrote such a book](http://www.fysnet.net/media_storage_devices.htm) a while back with all the juicy details.

Comment: Note that the floppy drive may be attached to USB (and for modern real hardware USB floppy drive is possibly less unlikely than an old ISA floppy controller). Trying to squeeze an adequate driver for an old ISA floppy disk controller into (less than) 512 bytes would be extremely challenging (not least of all due to the infamous unreliability of floppy media and the need for very robust error handling); and also squeezing drivers for several USB controllers and USB floppy drive into those same 512 bytes is entirely impossible.

Comment: Just for fun, [I had to try it](https://github.com/fysnet/FYSOS/tree/master/misc).  It only assumes the first controller and the first drive on that controller.  It does need a little more work, but it does show that it can be done, without assuming anything about the controller, and it does have error checking with an error report if an error is found.  It was an interesting experiment.

Comment: Nice; but you see what I mean about error handling (e.g. no "retry 3+ times, possibly with a reset every second retry").

Comment: Hrm. In theory, BIOS is supposed to load the first sector (NOT the first 512 bytes), and the old floppy drive hardware supports 16 KiB sectors; so you should be able to format the first track of a floppy with 16 KiB sector/s and have 16 KiB of boot sector code. Of course I'd expect that a lot of computers don't behave correctly and that there's a "very significant" risk that it won't work in practice.